# How to delete an image on Imageshack using its API

Tags: api, imageshack

I'm trying to use the Imageshack api to delete an image uploaded to my account.

I have successfully managed to upload an image to it using the API.

```
https://www.imageshack.us/upload_api.php?url=[URL_OF_THE_IMAGE]&key=[MY_KEY]
```

I can delete the image uploaded by using the standard interface.

Any solution using the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed it by doing the following:

First log in to get an auth_token:

```
HTTP POST
https://api.imageshack.us/v1/user/login?username=YOUR_USERNAME&password=YOUR_PASSWORD
```

Parse "auth_token" from the response

Then delete:

```
HTTP DELETE
https://api.imageshack.us/v1/images/SERVER/FILENAME?auth_token=AUTHTOKEN
```

In addition to AUTHTOKEN you need include SERVER and FILENAME, I store these from files.server and files.image.filename that come back in the response to the upload API call.

Answer (score 0):

Jamie Clark's solution is what you need, using the proper v1 api. Your sample script is still using the posting methodology from their older API [as described here](https://code.google.com/p/imageshackapi/wiki/ImageshackAPI). That one doesn't expose any deletion methods. What Jamie is describing is [the API as it is currently, documented here](http://api.imageshack.us/). It's not clear if the API keys are the same, but I'm guessing no - my new one doesn't seem to work with this old call and the link from that google code page for requesting an API key is defunct.